# Launch a Batch file from another computer using Command Line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a computer on which I have a server running. The computer has no screen attached to it and is running 24/7.
If the server crashes or something like that I want to be able to start it again without having to connect a screen to it. 
Can I start the .bat file from the cmd on my other computer? If so, am I able to see the logs from the server on my other computer(the one with screen)?
Both computers are running Windows.

Comment: Accessing one machine from another is exactly what a Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) does. You don't need a batch file, and you can directly start your server through the RDC and view the logs and pretty much do everything else you could if you had a screen and keyboard attached to the computer itself.

Comment: Thanks! I will check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solwed it using the RDC tool. It works great!